# Función buscar_compras() no realiza la búsqueda

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo una lista `compras = []` en la cual hay una serie de elementos si es que se decide agregar mediante una función aparte.

Pero esta función, la que seria la encargada de buscar en esa lista, no busca los elementos que hayan sido previamente ingresados por la otra función.

```
compras = []

def agregar_compras():
    pr_nom = input("Ingresa un elemento para agregar a la lista de compras: ")
    if pr_nom in compras:
        print("Este elemento ya fue agregado a la lista de compras!")
    pr_can = int(input("Ingresa la cantidad a comprar: "))
    if pr_can == 0:
        print("Ingrese una cantidad mayor a 0!")
    else:
        print("Elemento agregado exitosamente!")
    nom_can = [pr_nom, pr_can]
    compras.append(nom_can)
    #funcion para agregar cosas a la lista de compras

def buscar_compras():
    buscar = input("Ingrese un elemento a buscar en la lista de compras: ")
    if buscar in compras:
        print(f"{buscar} ya esta en la lista de compras.")
    else:
        print("Este elemento no fue agregado a la lista de compras.")
    compras.append(buscar)
    #no busca en la lista compras, directamente muestra que el elemento no fue agregado
```

Espero puedan ayudarme y por favor, cualquier otro error que puedan ver y corregirme es mas que bienvenido para mejorar, gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que `compras` es una lista de **tuplas**, por lo que preguntar si un **string** está en la lista nunca va a resultar:

```
string != tupla
```

Tienes dos opciones: una es implementar una función de búsqueda dentro de la lista:

```
def buscar_en_lista(codigo):
    for elemento in compras:
        if codigo == elemento[0]:
            return True
    return False
```

La función recibe el código (nombre) del producto tal cual lo ingresa el usuario y retorna `True` si ya está en la lista.

La segunda opción (mejor) es usar un diccionario en lugar de una lista. El diccionario está indexado por código (nombre) y contiene la cantidad a comprar:

```
compras = {}

def agregar_compras():
    pr_nom = input("Ingresa un elemento para agregar a la lista de compras: ")
    if pr_nom in compras.keys():
        print("Este elemento ya fue agregado a la lista de compras!")
    else:
        pr_can = int(input("Ingresa la cantidad a comprar: "))
        if pr_can == 0:
            print("Ingrese una cantidad mayor a 0!")
        else:
            print("Elemento agregado exitosamente!")
        compras[pr_nom] = pr_can
        #funcion para agregar cosas a la lista de compras
```

(Otro problema es que el código original siempre pide la cantidad, aun cuando el item ya exista en la lista).

#### Demo

Esta demo pide productos hasta completar 3 items en la lista de compras.

```
compras = {}

def agregar_compras():
    pr_nom = input("Ingresa un elemento para agregar a la lista de compras: ")
    if pr_nom in compras.keys():
        print("Este elemento ya fue agregado a la lista de compras!")
    else:
        pr_can = int(input("Ingresa la cantidad a comprar: "))
        if pr_can == 0:
            print("Ingrese una cantidad mayor a 0!")
        else:
            print("Elemento agregado exitosamente!")
        compras[pr_nom] = pr_can
        #funcion para agregar cosas a la lista de compras

while len(compras) < 3:
    agregar_compras()

print(compras)
```

produce:

```
Ingresa un elemento para agregar a la lista de compras: pan
Ingresa la cantidad a comprar: 10
Elemento agregado exitosamente!
Ingresa un elemento para agregar a la lista de compras: pan
Este elemento ya fue agregado a la lista de compras!
Ingresa un elemento para agregar a la lista de compras: leche
Ingresa la cantidad a comprar: 6
Elemento agregado exitosamente!
Ingresa un elemento para agregar a la lista de compras: cafe
Ingresa la cantidad a comprar: 1
Elemento agregado exitosamente!
{'pan': 10, 'leche': 6, 'cafe': 1}

Process finished with exit code 0
```